# Select from multiple tables matching multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I am working with 3 tables, trying to pull a list that match certain criteria.
I need a list of companies from the companies table, that have an active opportunity (iactive is 1 in opportunities table) AND have a record in the notes table of type order or order2.

```
 Companies Table
+------+------------------+
| cid  |     ccyname      |
+------+------------------+
| 1c   | Bobs Fish        |
| 2c   | Sheep Counters   |
| 3c   | Old Timers       |
| 4c   | Roasted Nuts     |
+------+------------------+

   Notes Table
+------+--------+--------+
| nid  |ntype   |cid     |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1n   | order  |3c      |
| 2n   | quest  |1c      |
| 3n   | order2 |2c      |
| 4n   | cancel |2c      |
+------+--------+--------+

Opportunities Table
+------+--------+--------+
| oid  |iactive | cid    |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1o   | 1      | 1c     |
| 2o   | 0      | 3c     |
| 3o   | 1      | 3c     |
| 4o   | 1      | 2c     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

With this example the results should be:

```
     Results
+----------------+--------+
| ccyname        |  oid   |
+----------------+--------+
| Old Timers     | 3o     |
| Sheep Counters | 4o     |
+----------------+--------+
```

Which would give me only companies that have both an active opportunity and an order or order2 note.

I have tried building this a few different ways, but I always end up with just one result or with too many. Could I get some help?

This is on SQL Server 2005.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Can you list one of your attempts?

Comment: No, this is for our CRM system at work, trying to set up a report.

Unfortunately I am still learning SQL, so my attempts were mostly with Access and the query designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ccyname), oid
FROM Companies AS c
INNER JOIN Notes AS n ON c.cid = n.cid
INNER JOIN Opportunities AS o ON c.cid = o.cid 
WHERE n.ntype IN ('order','order2')
AND o.iactive = 1;
```

*Caveat: Not Tested.*

Comment: I was able to get this to work and give me several results, I believe this will work. After I check the results I will report back on any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    C.ccyname, O.oid
FROM
    Companies C
    JOIN
    Opportunities O AND O.cid = c.cid
WHERE
    O.iactive = 1
    AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Notes N
        WHERE N.ntype IN ('order', 'order2') AND N.cid = c.cid)
```

Comment: +1 Although other solutions will give the same result, I think using Exists matches the request of "have a record in the notes table of type order or order2" the most. Also, fields from the notes table are not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cid, ccyname
FROM Companies c
INNER JOIN Notes n ON n.cid = c.cid AND n.ntype = 'order2' OR n.ntype = 'order'
INNER JOIN Opportunities o ON o.cid = c.cid AND o.iactive = 1
```